# Fetch particular line content from file stored in an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a file, and I need to take a `count` value from the file.

I am storing all the contents of the file in an array and later searching for that particular line (`Total number of lines in file is`).  And again using regex, I am taking out the `count`.

Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

my @array = <DATA>;

print Dumper(\@array);

my $count = 0;

my @matches = grep { /Total number of lines in file is/ } @array;

foreach (@matches){
    $count = $1 if($_ =~ /Total number of lines in file is :\s*(\d+)\s*/);
}

print "Count:$count\n";

__DATA__
Below is your data file

This is test line A
This is test line B
This is test line C
This is test line D
This is test line E
This is test line F
This is test line G
This is test line H
This is test line I
This is test line J

Total number of lines in file is :10
```

Here I am using `grep` and `for` loop to take the `count` which is needed to me.

Is there any better way to do this?  So, using single grep I can take the `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to retain all the lines, and you are just interested in the matching line, you can simplify it to:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $count = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
    $count = $1 if /Total number of lines in file is :\s*(\d+)\s*/;
}
print "Count:$count\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's find it in another way:

```
my $str = do { local $/; <DATA>; };

print $1 if($str=~m/Total number of lines in file is :(\d+)/);
```

Comment: This will return the entire line once for every line that matched the pattern and had a number that isn't `0` in the capture group. For the example input that should be `1`. That's because `grep` doesn't `map`, it just throws away elements where the test returns false.

Answer (score -1):

if you are so keen to use grep instead of toolic's approach, use system grep or backticks :)
but you need to understand that firstly you read whole file in an array, and then you "grep" (loop through) all array items and check whether they match the regex. basically, you do the same but with additional memory waste

Comment: Agree!! I don't want to waste memory to do this operation.

Comment: You don't need to read in the entire file, or shell out to anything.